# Clear MudTextField after Enter key pressed

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

I am taking input from user into MudTextField. When user input some value and press ENTER key, the a method (OnKeyPressed) is called and some task is done and same MudTextField is remained focused. I want when execution of this method is done, then MudTextField should remain focused but all input text should be cleared. I have set the bind value to null, but it is not working. Please guide me how to do this.

```
<MudTextField Required="true"
    Disabled="true"
    @onkeypress="OnKeyPressed"
    Immediate="true"
    Margin="Margin.Dense"
    @bind-Value="Barcode"
    Label=""
    Variant="Variant.Outlined"
    Adornment="Adornment.Start"
    AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Person">
</MudTextField>

public async void OnKeyPressed(KeyboardEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == "Enter")
    {
        // some login is implemented here
        Barcode = null;
    }
}
```

Please guide me how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use the `OnKeyPress` property instead of `@onkeypress`
2. Set `TextUpdateSuppression` property to false.

```
<MudTextField Required="true"
              Disabled="false"
              TextUpdateSuppression="false"
              OnKeyPress="OnKeyPressed"
              Immediate="true"
              Margin="Margin.Dense"
              @bind-Value="Barcode"
              Label=""
              Variant="Variant.Outlined"
              Adornment="Adornment.Start"
              AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Person">
</MudTextField>
```

Comment: This has not make any difference. Text still remain there in MudTextField

Comment: @ShakilAhmed try the new updated answer.

Comment: still same result. MudTextField keeps the input value.

Comment: @ShakilAhmed I created a new Blazor server project using MudBlazor template and this code is working on it.

Comment: Try adding a @ref on the component and calling the Clear() method on it.